# What happens if I use the Coiling Grasp Tattoo on the same target multiple times?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

One of the new items in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* is the Coiling Grasp Tattoo, a rather interesting uncommon that lets you damage and grapple enemies at range if they fail a Strength saving throw. Fascinatingly, it has no limitations on its uses - it lasts until the target successfully escapes the grapple, you move too far away from it, or, importantly here,

> or if you use this tattoo on a different creature.

However, let's picture a situation where I have a creature grappled using this tattoo, and my best course of action is to use the tattoo on the same creature again, to try and deal damage to it if it fails the saving throw. This time, however, the creature passed its saving throw...

... but I did not use the tattoo on a *different* creature. Am I right to assume the target is still grappled, just doesn't take further damage this turn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## You are right, the target remains grappled.

The creature didn't break the current grapple. It just avoided your attack.

> The creature must succeed on a DC 14 Strength saving throw or take 3d6 force damage and be grappled by you.

To escape the grapple, it needs to spend its action to escape (or use some other clever way to escape).

> As an action, the creature can escape the grapple by succeeding on a DC 14 Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check.

Otherwise, the grapple will last until you cancel it or grapple something else.

> The grapple also ends if you halt it (no action required), if the creature is ever more than 15 feet away from you, or if you use this tattoo on a different creature.